# How to replace object index in NSMutableArray in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray

I have two different arrays and I want to check firstArray objects and accordingly insert objects in second array.If my firstArray contains particular object then at that index, I am trying insert value in secondArray.
Currently, I am inserting values like :

```
[secondArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:transIdArray];
[secondArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:fullCaseArray];
[secondArray replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:caseTitleArray];
[secondArray replaceObjectAtIndex:3 withObject:filingDateArray];
```

My problem is, If in firstArray transIdArray is at 2 index then my these two arrays data getting mismatched.Please suggest me better way to check add insert values in arrays. Thanks.

Comment: Please read through the SO [help file](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking questions. As written, your question does not meet the guideline. Specifically, please include a minimal, reproducible, example.

Answer (score 0):

`NSArray` elements are naturally packed together, not sparse, like C arrays can be.  To accomplish what you want, the secondArray needs to carry placeholders that are considered non-objects semantically by your app.  `[NSNull null]`, an instance of `NSNull` (not to be confused with `nil`) is a common choice.

You could initialize one or both arrays like this:

```
for (NSInteger i=0, i<SOME_KNOW_MAX_LENGTH; ++i) {
    [secondArray addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
```

Then an instance of `NSNull` in the second array means 'there's nothing at this index in this array corresponding to firstArray'.  And you can check if that condition holds for a given index like this:

```
id secondArrayElement = secondArray[index];
if ([secondArrayElement isMemberOfClass:[NSNull class]]) { // ...
```

As an aside - often, when I find myself needing to coordinate parallel arrays, it usually means I have some undone representational work, and what I really need is a single array with a more thoughtful object, or the containing object must be more thoughtfully designed.